# nodemailer not sending email in testing

Tags: node.js, email, nodemailer, mailtrap, itmstransporter

I am trying to sending email using MailTrap for Testing sendMail() always return error i tried all ports 25,2525,587

and this my function

```
const sendEmail = async (options) => {
  // Create a transporter
  const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    // host: process.env.EMAIL_HOST,
    host: "sandbox.smtp.mailtrap.io",
    port: 587,

    auth: {
      user: process.env.EMAIL_USERNAME,
      pass: process.env.EMAIL_PASSWORD,
    },

  });

  //email options
  const mailOptions = {
    from: "marim  <marim.khaled99@gmail.gom>",
    to: options.email,
    subject: options.subject,
    text: options.message,
    // html:
  };

  // send the email
  await transporter.sendMail(mailOptions);
};
```